# Providing/provided, do I need to use the comma?

Tags: clauses, commas

I have this sentence:

> They confirmed the system fulfills its intended use, providing that the
>   proper X with high enough resolution was used.

Is the comma there correct?

I am also not sure about the "high enough resolution"...resolution high enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your comma usage there is correct. The comma sets off the clause specifying the conditional, making the meaning explicit and matching the way that we'd say the sentence (a comma is voiced as a brief pause). Without the comma, it might appear to be a predicate construction stating the *use* was performing the act of *providing*.

*High enough resolution* is also correct. *Resolution high enough* is perfectly valid as well, but it requires a determiner of some sort for *resolution*; most likely the article *a*.

Comment: Thanks, just a small question - why there is no article required for the "resolution" in the first case?

Comment: Because in this case *high enough* provides the function that an article would when it's in front of *resolution*; it essentially tells us *which resolution(s)*. The two phrases have the same meaning but different grammatical structures. I encourage you to open a new question about this, since I've realized that a proper answer needs more than a comment to properly explain the situation. If you ask one, comment here again and I'll post an answer.